# What's wrong with my C++ Template code for Arduino?

Tags: arduino, c++

I'm trying to implement a C++ templated member function in Arduino 0022, but I'm getting an error in code which seems correct to me.

```
// in Settings.h
template <class T> void save( T variable );

// in Settings.cpp
template <class T> void Settings::save( T variable ) {
  Serial.println("Want to save a variable of size " + String( sizeof(T) ) );
};
```

> // compiler (linker) output
>   TimeMachineArduino.cpp.o: In function `SimpleScreen::left()`:
>
> SimpleScreen.h:85: undefined reference to `void Settings::save<int>(int)`
>
> SimpleScreen.h:86: undefined reference to `void Settings::save<double>(double)`
>
> SimpleScreen.h:87: undefined reference to `void Settings::save<char>(char)`

The `SimpleScreen::left()` function is where I'm implicitly instantiating the template functions (by calling save on an int, double, and char).

Comment: This is actually a C++ question. You should ask such questions on Stackoverflow.com. The answer to this question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/648900

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to move the contents of the `.cpp` file into the `.h` file. Separating declarations and definitions doesn't work for templates. See the link @sharptooth posted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/648900.